# Sorting and filtering in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a file in the following format:

```
somePlane (1,2,3) (1,0,0) (0,0,1) R
awsomePlane (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1) B
nicePlane (1,1,1) (2,4,7) (7,1,0) G
```

I'm trying to sort it [alphabetically according to the first column] and put it into an array while each line is an array element.

But I don't even manage to sort it and have no idea how to put each row into an array element.

I tried the following to sort but it didn't work:

```
sort -t" " -k1 myfile.txt
```

What can I do to sort it and insert it into array?

[EDIT]
I had a mistake and it seems I was able to sort it, but I still don't know how to insert each line into an array.
I used the following command to sort:

```
sort -t" " -f -k1 myfile.txt
```

Comment: What didn't work for your argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort and store the lines into an array as shown below:

```
# sort and create array
$ IFS=$'\n' arr=( $(sort file.txt) )

# access array elements
$ echo ${arr[0]}
awsomePlane (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1) B    

$ echo ${arr[1]}
nicePlane (1,1,1) (2,4,7) (7,1,0) G    

$ echo ${arr[2]}
somePlane (1,2,3) (1,0,0) (0,0,1) R
```

Comment: IFS is Internal Field Separator. You need to set it to the newline character because you want each element in the array to be one line of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bash 4.0 or newer, the best way is to use [readarray](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-readarray) (synonym for [mapfile](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile)) with redirection and [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#index-process-substitution), as it doesn't need loops and doesn't risk [pathname expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#index-pathname-expansion):

```
readarray -t ARRAY < <(exec sort -t" " -f -k1 myfile.txt)
```

Example output:

```
> for I in "${!ARRAY[@]}"; do echo "$I : ${ARRAY[I]}"; done
0 : awsomePlane (1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,1) B
1 : nicePlane (1,1,1) (2,4,7) (7,1,0) G
2 : somePlane (1,2,3) (1,0,0) (0,0,1) R
```